# Can an object be instantiated only once inside a linq query?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have to write a C# script, and I have to worry about three things: performance, number of characters and number of lines (only one semi-colon is allowed). I need to concatenate a list of strings, and this is my current approach (for readability sake, the snippet is slightly modified having names of variables changed and spaces added):

```
//note: stringList is of type List<string>

var builder = new StringBuilder();
string result = (from str in stringList select builder.Append("&q=" + str)).ToString();
```

the problem with this is it has two lines, so it doesn't work. is there a way to instantiate the string builder inside the LINQ query?

also, how good is the performance of this query compared to a simple foreach loop? (I know foreach isn't an option, I'm asking just for future reference)

Comment: It's not quite clear what are you asking for. What do you mean by "only once inside".

Comment: I need to instantiate the string builder object inside the querry.

Comment: `... select new StringBuilder().Append(...)`

Comment: *Why* do you need to instantiate it inside the LINQ query?

Comment: Also, why are you calling `.ToString()` on the LINQ query? This is almost certainly not going to produce the result you want. Or if it does, your question is very unclear.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen you're right, it doesn't. I created a Console Application to test it and yes, I was calling ToString on a query. (I couldn't test inside the script execution environment because it had two semi-colons)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works a treat if you want to use `StringBuilder`:

```
string result =
    stringList
        .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, s) => sb.Append("&q=" + s))
        .ToString();
```

The easy answer is:

```
string result = String.Join("", stringList.Select(s => "&q=" + s));
```

Answer (score 6):

You worry about "pre-optimisation", don't overthink it in advance.

As far your query goes, this is the right way to do it:

```
var result = "&q" + String.Join("&q=", stringList);
```

Comment: Why converting to array? Lists should be perfectly joinable too

Comment: Thanks! the good thing about this answer is it saves several characters! But considering that stackoverflow is a knowledge base and trying to make this question more relevant to a greater number of people who might need to instantiate something like a string builder inside a LINQ query, I reiterate the question.

Comment: This also produces a different result, it will not prefix the first string with `&q=`.

Comment: @FinnTheHuman, it is extremely unlikely that anyone, beyond those playing with artificially restrictive requirements like yourself, would ever try to instantiate a string builder within a linq expression. So this answer is actually useful, beyond just answering your odd question.

Comment: @RoyalBg Pre-optimisation again ;) I've changed the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a StringBuilder at all, this is a one-line replacement for your code:

```
string result = string.Join("", from str in stringList select "&q=" + str));
```